# slqalchemy core pagination with flask when we pass text fragments to generate the sql and python

Tags: python, pagination, sqlalchemy

For a simple select, pagination works as implemented here:

```
mheader_dict = dict(request.headers)
no_of_pgs = 0

if 'Maxpage' in mheader_dict.keys():
    max_per_pg = int(mheader_dict['Maxpage'])
else:
    max_per_pg = 100
page_no = int(request.headers.get('Pageno', type=int, default=1))
offset1 = (page_no - 1) * max_per_pg
s = select[orders]
if s is not None:
    s = s.limit(max_per_pg).offset(offset1)
    rs = g.conn.execute(s)
```

Conn is the connection object above

When text is used in the select statement, How to specify the limit?.How to rectify in below:

```
s1 = text('select d.*, (select array(select localities.name from localities, localities_boys where localities.id = localities_boys.locality_id and localities_boys.boy_id = d.id and localities_boys.boy_id is not null )) from delivery_boys d order by d.id;')
page_no = int(request.headers.get('Pageno', type=int, default=1))
offset1 = (page_no - 1) * max_per_pg
s1 = s1.limit(max_per_pg).offset(offset1)
rs1 = g.conn.execute(s1)
```

**If s1 = s1.compile(engine) is used, it returns sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGCompiler_psycopg2 object which doesn't have limit functionality**

**How to convert sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause to sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select  using sqlalchemy core 1.0.8 to solve the above?**

using sqlalchemy core v. 1.0.8, python 2.7,flask 0.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted the TextClause to Select as :

```
 s1 = select([text('d.*, (select array(select localities.name from localities, localities_boys where localities.id = localities_boys.locality_id and localities_boys.boy_id = d.id and localities_boys.boy_id is not null)) from delivery_boys d')])
```

Hence able to use limit and offset on the generated Select object